# Will Adobe CS5 with Java SE 6 runtime work on 10.11 El Capitan?

Tags: macos, adobe

I am running OS X 10.10 Yosemite which happily runs my Adobe CS 5.0.  When I upgraded from 10.8 to 10.10, I had to install Java SE 6 runtime.

In parallel, I also run the latest Java, with browsers set to ask before running it. All seems to work ok.

If I upgrade to OS X 10.11 El Capitan, is Adobe CS 5 likely to continue working?

(I totally depend on my legit copy of CS 5, and I don't have the revenue stream to support ongoing Creative Cloud membership.)

Comment: Why use Java 6 instead of upgrading?

Comment: CS5 requires Java 6.  I also run the latest Java for everything that uses Java (notably, one government website).

Comment: I was thinking more in relation to newer Java, but OK.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to install the Java version from https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

From that link:

"Java for OS X 2015-001 installs the legacy Java 6 runtime for OS X 10.11 El Capitan, OS X 10.10 Yosemite, OS X 10.9 Mavericks, OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, and OS X 10.7 Lion.

This package is exclusively intended for support of legacy software and installs the same deprecated version of Java 6 included in the 2014-001 and 2013-005 releases.

Quit any Java applications before installing this update."

After installing and restarting you can use the Java preferences pane in System Preferences to control which Java version you would like to use.

Answer (score 1):

ProTip: Use Chrome to download the legacy **Java6** for OS X 2017-001 from this page http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572 . For some strange reason Safari just does not cut it.

This package is exclusively intended for support of **legacy software** and installs the same deprecated version of Java 6 included in the 2015-001, 2014-001, and 2013-005 releases. The newer OS X (macOS) becomes the less chances you have to keep Photoshop CS5 running. Also you will not be able to open the raw file format of new camera's.