# Download and Install Photoshop CS5

Tags: macos, install, adobe-photoshop

I want to transfer a legal, licensed copy of Photoshop CS5 from and old Lion iMac I am de-commissioning to my current El Capitan system.  I have the license number, but not the install media as this copy of Photoshop started off as CS3 and then I did an online upgrade to CS5.  So I don't have CS5 install disks.

So I go to [Download CS5 products](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/cs5-product-downloads.html) and download the OS X install file for Photoshop CS5.  However when I went to run the installer I was presented with this:

[image: Photoshop CS5 Install fail]

Obviously something has gone wrong.  However I am not sure if this is an artifact related to not having Java 6 installed (See [Will Adobe CS5 with Java SE runtime work on 10.11 El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242548/will-adobe-cs5-with-java-se-6-runtime-work-on-10-11-el-capitan)) or if the file is actually hosed.  But [Is it possible to use Adobe CS5 with Java SE 7?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150952/is-it-possible-to-use-adobe-cs5-with-java-se-7) makes me think I should get past an install.

I don't believe that I have Java installed (and I only saw that question when I was composing this one), but I also don't want to have to jump through hoops to get CS5 up and running again.

---

**Update** - When I right click on the installer and select `Show Package Contents` I appear to be able to see the internals without any problem.

Comment: You can *install* without Java so this is an issue with the download being damaged. You might try another browser or clearing your browser cache and rebooting.

Comment: @user3439894 That does not make a difference and I *can* see the package contents

Comment: @user3439894 And that's why I said *That does not make a difference*

Comment: Under **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **General** > **Allow apps downloaded from:**, what is selected?  If it’s not **Anywhere**, then  select **Anywhere** and then eject and remount the DMG file and try installing again. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @user3439894  The security was the issue.  But it was not presented in a very user friendly manner.  Plus I would have expected OS X to recognize Adobe.  Anyway Its all moot as CS5 won't accept my CS3 license number and I certainly don't have the upgrade media any more nor can I find record to show adobe.  Plus the Java issue etc

Comment: @PeterM Have you tried contacting Adobe about this? I had a similar experience a while back and they had a record of my earlier registration and were able to provide me with what I needed to install Adobe CS 5.

Comment: @Monomeeth I'm in half a mind about contacting adobe or not.  I'm feeling it may be time from me to move on from them rather than use an outdated program that requires java to be enabled (and a specific version of java at that)

Comment: @Monomeeth FWIW Adobe only knows about my CS3 license key and not the upgrade I did to CS5.  They are so sorry but they can't help me.

Comment: @PeterM That's a real pain! I also don't think Adobe are as customer-focused as they once used to be. :( Unless something has recently changed, users *can* still opt to purchase Adobe CS6 as their last *perpetual licence* product, although I don't know how well CS6 will continue to work as macOS continues to go through major changes. And, as you said, it may just be time to move on from them anyway.

Comment: @Monomeeth I ended up extracting my CS5 license via some command line-fu and a windows program with no help from Adobe.  But from what I have seen you can't buy CS6 any more,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment from user3439894 the issue was that I had

> System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General > Allow apps
>   downloaded from:

set to

> Mac App Store and identified developers

Once I set it to be

> Anywhere

Then I could run the installer.

The error message I received was disingenuous and did not inform me of what the actual problem was.

---

Protip - Even though Adobe wouldn't tell me what my CS5 license number was there *are* ways to extract it from OS X.  It just took some googling.

Comment: Simple and easy to download and install [adobe photoshop cs5 full version download](http://fileparrots.blogspot.com/2017/08/download-adobe-photoshop-cs5-free.html).